# How to remove vcpkg and all libraries installed with vcpkg

Tags: vcpkg

How does one completely remove vcpkg and all installations/system changes made by it?

I recall seeing some FAQ about vcpkg where it said that you could just delete the vcpkg folder. However, I've been trying to find that same FAQ for over an hour now, to no avail. Also "just delete the folder" being the solution seems implausible to me, since I would assume vcpkg changes some environment variables or other settings, as well as the integration with Visual Studio that I was trying to use. Online search on this topic only yielded people discussing how to remove multiple installed libraries at once, with no clear solution even to that problem (I would be interested in this as well). The vcpkg website itself seems to offer no answers to this question.

edit: I found the page saying "just delete the folder" at [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019).

Comment: just delete the folder as suggested. if you are going re install it in another directory location then also delete the existing vcpkg location and remove/modify any associated environmental variable you have set that refers the old installation location.

Comment: May also want to do `vcpkg integrate remove` if you ran `vcpkg integrate install` before.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg offers the instruction how to uninstall:

> ### Uninstall vcpkg
>
> Just delete the directory.

It [could also mention](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/pull/1795) that removing the vcpkg directory completely actually uninstalls all the installed libraries (all ports), because the vcpkg directory is the sole place where `vcpkg.exe` deploys any files.

Additionally, if you did run `vcpkg integrate install`, then you may also run `vcpkg integrate remove` to remove the user-wide (global) integration.
vcpkg integrate remove  Remove user-wide integration

Comment: There is also a `vcpkg` directory in the `AppData\Local` one. It contains an `archive` sub-directory with all built packages and also a `config` file with `User-Id` and other personal information.

Comment: For Linux or macOS, the vcpkg binary cache folder is at `~/.cache/vcpkg/archives/`.  These can be listed with the following command (requires `unzip`): `find ~/.cache/vcpkg/archives -name *.zip -type f -exec bash -c 'echo;unzip -c "$0" CONTROL  -x */* 2>/dev/null | grep --color=never -E "(Archive|Package|^Version|Feature)"' '{}' \;`

Comment: Libraries in the vcpkg binary cache on Linux can be listed with the following one-liner:

`find ~/.cache/vcpkg/archives -name '*.zip' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo;unzip -c "$0" CONTROL  -x */* 2>/dev/null | grep --color=never -E "(Archive|Package|^Version)" | sort -u' '{}' \;`

This is a refinement to the command in my previous comment, which was noisier and did not always succeed.  This command may require modifications to run on macOS.

Comment: @MikeOnline this should be an answer targeted towards Linux users. In any case, thank you